# Jenkins Versioning Artefacts Automatically

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My Jenkins builds my maven repo that is stored in GitHub. I have three main branches:

- `Master`
- `Develop`
- `Release_xx`

What I store in Master is the results of the release branch being merged into Master, and therefore my production branch.

My Jenkins builds the Master branch, but the best i can figure out for versioning is to use the `git_commit`, `git_branch` and `build_number`.

### Question:

I want to be able to version my artefacts like this `0.14.5` for my `master` branch. So this would be `0`.`release`.`increment`

I want to be able to automate the bumping of the minor version, and I don't mind manually changing the major version.
I normally pass in variables using `mvn install -Dvariable=value`.

Please, can someone help guide me! Ideally, i do not want to install the maven release plugin. I would prefer to use a script or a jenkins plugin.

Comment: First thought about this would be to use versions-maven-plugin in combination with [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html) which can be called in a separate pipeline step in Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plugin+-+Release+Management plugin? 
 This plugin helped me to automate the release process.